# How to get text value from Listview Edit Text feild.....?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, getvalue

How to get the values from the edit text .

Hello everyone im facing a problem with android task in which there so many edit text available in the edit text .

[image]

**i need to get the values from 1 to 4 all edit texts ..?**
Below is my  get view method of Adapter.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.social_media_row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.social_id = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.socialMediaId);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.social_id.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                  Log.i("AfterTextChange",holder.social_id.getText().toString());
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        SocialMediaModel contact = contactsList.get(position);

        holder.social_id.setText(contact.getSocialMediaId());

        holder.social_id.setTag(contact);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Update   :   i want to get the values when user click on the button

```
savebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

  /here what i can do    


            }
        });
```

Comment: Do have any button in your Adapter ??

Comment: when you want to get values ?? any button Click event ?

Comment: yes  Button  There a Save Button Available

Comment: there if four EDITTEXT is fixed ?

Comment: Please use a list view with much more edit texts so the user has to scroll. You will see that you loose your text while scrolling. Solve this first.

Comment: yes edit text are fixed but count is 7  in image it's just demo

Comment: I can see only one `EditText` in this code. Where are the rest? Or is it like one `EditText` in a row?

Comment: and button is after the Edit text ?? means first four Edittext and then button ?

Comment: no no there only one button     to get the all values

Answer (score 1):

```
        //at top Globally declare it
        private String[] valueList = new String[];

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    final ViewHolder holder;
                    if (convertView == null) {

                        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.social_media_row, null);

                        holder = new ViewHolder();

                        holder.social_id = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.socialMediaId);

                        convertView.setTag(holder);

                        holder.social_id.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                         valueList[pos] = s.toString();

                            }
                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                              Log.i("AfterTextChange",holder.social_id.getText().toString());
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    }

                    SocialMediaModel contact = contactsList.get(position);

                    holder.social_id.setText(contact.getSocialMediaId());

                    holder.social_id.setTag(contact);
                    return convertView;
                }

// method to  get Values
public String[] getValueList(){
        return valueList;
    }
```

Now on button click event put this code

```
String[] myvl = yourAdapteName.getValueList();
```

Comment: @sunny: I have small update with the previous. Would you please try again!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a method like this one for each EditText with the list position as parameter :

```
public String getValueFromFirstEditText(int position){
      //here you need to recreate the id for the first editText
     String result = textValues.get("theFirstEditTextAtPos:"+position);
     if(result ==null)
          result = "default value";
 return result;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**i hope this code help you**

USE Adapter cell position

follow this code

in getView(in Adapter Class)

```
edittext.getText().toString();
```

Comment: explain  more  ..please

Comment: you use custom adapter ?

Comment: can you send that class

Comment: does this 4 edittext belongs to same cell of listview ?

Comment: holder.item_Image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.social_id.getText().toString;
            }
        });

Comment: then what you went bro explain me

Comment: hahahahhhaa   bhai tu abhi bacha  ha    rahie de tare bs ki bat nahi   it's  list view there more then 4 edit text   .
in image i just  used to explain the situation

Comment: adapter and main class are in same

Comment: complete code is there  without xml   files  i think your new to android development

Answer (score 0):

Declare this in your declaration

```
    protected AdapterView.OnItemClickListener messageClickedHandler;
```

Click event for the list view using Adapter view

```
   messageClickedHandler = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String strName=rowItems.get(position).getStrName();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Name : "+strName , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        list.setOnItemClickListener(messageClickedHandler);
    }
```

rowItems is an array list Object , getStrName() from the user defined class.

Comment: this is not related with my question bro